How to make sure the command in if-else isn't skipped while using tkinter?
I would like to make users answer random question using tkinter, but that's not possible here because of some reason, the questions got skipped until the last question.
Code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, END
from tkinter import *
import random

def qna():
    qna = tk.Tk()
    qna.title("Quiz")
    question = 1
    attempt = 1
    uscore = 0
    answer = 0
    while question <=10:
        num1 = random.randint(0, 9)
        num2 = random.randint(0, 9)
        score = num1 + num2
        while True:
            while True:
                try:
                    tk.Label(qna, text = f"Question {question}, Attempt {attempt}\nWhat's the answer for {num1} + {num2}?: ").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
                    answer_entry = tk.Entry(qna)
                    answer_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
                    qna.btnSubmitAnswer = tk.Button(qna, text="Submit", command=qna_submit).grid(row=2, column=0)
                    break
                except Exception:
                    messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please try again with a number.")
                    continue
            if answer == score:
                print("Bravo", "That's correct. Good job!")
                attempt = 1
                question += 1
                uscore += 1
                answer_entry.delete(0, END)
                break
            elif answer != score and attempt == 3:
                print(f"That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is {score}")
                attempt = 1
                question += 1
                answer_entry.delete(0, END)
                break
            elif answer != score:
                print("That's wrong, please try again.")
                attempt += 1
                continue
    qna.mainloop()
    
def qna_submit():
    qna.answer = qna.answer_entry.get()
    
qna()

Output:
(this include the tkinter, but the only one that popped out is when it writes Question 10)
the only GUI that popped out after all that output
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 5
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 10
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 12
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 11
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 8
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 9
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 12
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 9
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 14
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, please try again.
That's wrong, you ran out of attempt. The answer is 10

How do I fix that? I'm confused on how to explain the problem
I tried using BlackBox.AI to fix it and it tells me to do this, but none of the GUI popped out
(this is before I add qna.mainloop())
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, END
from tkinter import *
import random

def qna():
    qna = tk.Tk()
    qna.title("Quiz")
    question = 1
    attempt = 1
    uscore = 0
    answer = 0

    def qna_submit(answer_entry, answer):
        answer = answer_entry.get()
        if answer == str(score):
            messagebox.showinfo("Bravo", "That's correct. Good job!")
            attempt = 1
            question += 1
            uscore += 1
            answer_entry.delete(0, END)
        elif attempt == 3:
            messagebox.showinfo("Out of attempts", f"That's wrong, you ran out of attempts. The answer is {score}")
            attempt = 1
            question += 1
            answer_entry.delete(0, END)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Wrong answer", "That's wrong, please try again.")
            attempt += 1

    while question <= 10:
        num1 = random.randint(0, 9)
        num2 = random.randint(0, 9)
        score = num1 + num2
        while True:
            try:
                tk.Label(qna, text = f"Question {question}, Attempt {attempt}\nWhat's the answer for {num1} + {num2}?: ").grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
                answer_entry = tk.Entry(qna)
                answer_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
                btnSubmitAnswer = tk.Button(qna, text="Submit", command=lambda: qna_submit(answer_entry, answer))
                btnSubmitAnswer.grid(row=2, column=0)
                break
            except Exception:
                messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please try again with a number.")
                continue

qna()

I'm so dumbfounded right now I don't know how to fix this issue. I want it to come out one by one from Question 1 till Question 10.

Local variables inside a function are not attributes of the function name. You can't refer to qna.answer and qna.answer_entry from outside the function.

You also don't understand the asynchronous nature of tkinter. qna() doesn't wait for you to fill in the entry. None of the Tkinter widgets show until you call mainloop(), which is after your loop is done.

Here's a tutorial on how to create a quiz using tkinter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfV1a3ri1tk

What is this def qna(): and qna = tk.Tk() You cannot use duplicate of qna

Here is image...   https://ibb.co/6n2Bdcn

It's alright, I found a way to fix it. Thanks yall for the comments

It's alright, I found a way to fix it. Thanks yall for the comments
